# C# DataGridTextColumn line break

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, line-breaks, datagridtextcolumn

There must be a simple solution for this, but I just can't find it. I have a DataGrid with DataGridTextColumns which contain data. This is working fine. I just seem to not get the String inside the Cells to make a line break, instead everything is in one line (no matter how long the string is).

```
dataGrid.IsReadOnly = true;
dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGrid.ItemsSource = ConvertListIntoPlantViewModel(lList);

DataGridTextColumn textColumn1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
DataGridTextColumn textColumn2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
DataGridTextColumn textColumn3 = new DataGridTextColumn();
textColumn3.MaxWidth = 200;

textColumn1.Header = "Name";
textColumn1.Binding = new Binding("Name");
textColumn2.Header = "Type";
textColumn2.Binding = new Binding("Type");
textColumn3.Header = "Info";
textColumn3.Binding = new Binding("Information");

dataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn1);
dataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn2);
dataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn3);
```

Let's say I want to make the Text, which ends up in textColumn3 to make a line break at the end of the cell (which is 200 wide). How do I achieve this? There must be a simple Style Element that can be set, right? I just can't find it.

Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There must be a simple Style Element that can be set, right? I just can't find it.

Yes, you could set the ElementStyle property of the column(s) to the following Style for the text to wrap:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
</Style>
```

You could create the Style programmatically using the XamlReader.Parse method:

```
string xaml = "<Style xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" TargetType=\"TextBlock\"><Setter Property=\"TextWrapping\" Value=\"Wrap\"/></Style>";
Style style = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(xaml) as Style;

DataGridTextColumn textColumn1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
textColumn1.ElementStyle = style;
```

Comment: Thanks, I prefer the programmatical approach. It works perfectly! :) TY